How can I write this code without using variables
I have the following code that checks surface area of a product and spits out a number.
However, it's very efficient.
How can I write this code with Case When, Then instead of variables and if else?
DECLARE @test DECIMAL(10,2) 

SELECT
    @test = ([WIDTH] / 1000) * ([HEIGHT] / 1000)
FROM
    MAIN.SYSADM.[TABLE]
WHERE
    ID = 854037
    AND POS_NR = 1 


IF (@test > 1)
    BEGIN
    (
    SELECT
        TOP(1)
        360 / SUM(CAST([QTY] AS INT))
    FROM
        MAIN.SYSADM.[TABLE]
    WHERE
        ID = 854037
        AND POS_NR = 1 
        AND BOM_PRODUKT NOT IN (52101,52102,52006,52007,52003,52005,52008,53201,53102)
        AND (
            STL_PRODGRP IN (26,27,28,30,33,35,412,413,415,425,426,427)
            OR BOM_PRODUKT = 50002
        )
    GROUP BY
        BOM_NODE
    )
    END

ELSE
    BEGIN
    (
    SELECT
        TOP(1)
        180 / SUM(CAST([QTY] AS INT))
    FROM
        MAIN.SYSADM.[TABLE]
    WHERE
        ID = 854037
        AND POS_NR = 1 
        AND BOM_PRODUKT NOT IN (52101,52102,52006,52007,52003,52005,52008,53201,53102)
        AND (
            STL_PRODGRP IN (26,27,28,30,33,35,412,413,415,425,426,427) 
            OR BOM_PRODUKT = 50002
        )
    GROUP BY
        BOM_NODE
    ) 
    END

I tried this but the top(1) and GROUP by doesn't work
SELECT
    (
    SELECT
        TOP(1)
        (
        CASE
            WHEN CAST(([WIDTH] / 1000) * ([HEIGHT] / 1000) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) > 1
            THEN 360 / SUM(CAST([QTY] AS INT))
            ELSE 180 / SUM(CAST([QTY] AS INT))
        END
        )
    )
FROM
    MAIN.SYSADM.[TABLE]
WHERE
    [ID] = 854037
    AND POS_NR = 1 
    AND BOM_PRODUKT NOT IN (52101,52102,52006,52007,52003,52005,52008,53201,53102)
    AND (
        STL_PRODGRP IN (26,27,28,30,33,35,412,413,415,425,426,427)
        OR BOM_PRODUKT = 50002
    )
GROUP BY
    BOM_NODE  


Note that a TOP without an ORDER BY is a sure sign of a flaw. This means that the data engine is free to return what ever arbitrary row(s) it wants, and the row(s) could be different every time you run said query. If you are using TOP you need to ensure the query has a deterministic ORDER BY so that you get consistent and reliable results.

There are many things in here that raise questions for me. Why are you storing Qty as anything other than an int? Do you understand integer math? You are doing some weird things with division and casting as a decimal to determine if the result is greater than an int. In essence your datatypes are clearly all over the place which is not fun to work with.

Perhaos I'm  missing it, but isn't the only difference between your 2 queries whether dividend is 180 or 360?

However, it's very efficient. that's good, no

You might as well use width * height > 1000000 unless you are in fact relying on integer division in some way -- which seems doubtful considering the cast to decimal.

In what way did it not work? I'm guessing that it started producing multiple rows rather than just one.

I get this. Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Column 'MAIN.SYSADM.TABLE.WIDTH' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Column 'MAIN.SYSADM.TABLE.STL_HEIGHT' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I need to figure out where to put the Top(1) so it will work with Group by

What is the purpose of the whole width/height calculation? You clearly have multiple rows coming back from that search but the selecting into a variable was masking that by silently keeping only the "last" one (which is arbitrary without an order by.) You need to figure out what you need to query before trying to pin it down with top.

You have a syntax error in the first query. It won't even run: select @test = ([WIDTH]/1000)*(HEIGHT]/1000)

White space and formatting matter. Edited code. Added missing [ to [HEIGHT].

If your data contains multiple rows having ID = 854037 and POS_NR = 1, your @test calculation is actually calculating multiple results, the last of which is retained by the select @test = ... statement. If every such row has the same WIDTH and HEIGHT values, all results will be the same and it doesn't matter which is selected.
Once you place this calculation in the WHEN clause of a CASE expression, only one result is permitted. If all of the results are the same, you can apply a MIN(), MAX(), or TOP 1 to limit the results to just that one value.
The updated query would be something like:
select --top(1)
    BOM_NODE,
    SUM(QTY) as SumQty,
    MAX((WIDTH/1000)*(HEIGHT/1000)) as MaxArea,
    case when (
        select MAX((WIDTH/1000)*(HEIGHT/1000))
        from [TABLE]
        where ID=854037 and POS_NR=1
        ) > 1
    then 360/SUM(CAST(QTY as int))
    else 180/SUM(CAST(QTY as int))
    end as Result 
from [TABLE]
where ID = 854037
and POS_NR = 1 
and BOM_PRODUKT not in (52101,52102,52006,52007,52003,52005,52008,53201,53102)
and (
    STL_PRODGRP in (26,27,28,30,33,35,412,413,415,425,426,427)
    or BOM_PRODUKT = 50002
)
group by BOM_NODE

I commented out the top 1 and added a few extra columns to show some of the intermediate results. I also cleaned up some of the formatting for improved readability.
Using some test data I generated, I got the following results:



BOM_NODE
SumQty
MaxArea
Result




1
30
1.5
12


2
5
1.5
72






BOM_NODE
SumQty
MaxArea
Result




1
30
0.5
6


2
5
0.5
36



See this db<>fiddle for a demo.
I also believe you have some serious database design issues if you are storing product attributes (like width and height) in the same table as quantities. I suggest that you read up on "database normalization" and apply some of those techniques to improve your data model.
Expressions like CAST(QTY as int) are also suspicious. Are you storing numeric values as text? Don't.
